# CodeModel / Jinvocation with JMethod.body()

Tags: code-generation, sun-codemodel

I have the next JInvocation:

```
JInvocation jInvoke = JExpr.invoke(anotherPageInstance, method);
```

where `anotherPageInstance` is `JVar` and method is `JMethod`.

I do some actions on this `JInvocation`, and then I want to add it to `test.body().invoke` where test is `JMethod`.

The main problem is that I can't, because `test.body().invoke` has no option to get `JInvocation` as argument.

I can do the next: `test.body().invoke(anotherPageInstance, method)`, but this doesn't help me, because I want to save the `JInvocation`, and just when some conditions are taking place, add this `Jinvocation` to the body (and as I mentions before, meanwhile I do some action on this `JInvocation`).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an invocation the body (`JBlock`) by using the `add()` method:

```
test.body().add(jInvoke);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating JInvocation with JExpr.invoke(), use the JExpr factory methods:

```
public static JInvocation invoke(JExpression lhs,
                                 JMethod method)
public static JInvocation invoke(JExpression lhs,
                                 String method)
```

See [JExpr](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JExpr.html#invoke(com.sun.codemodel.JMethod)).